# How to distort still image or gif animation

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes, distort, npr

I found this gif animation in Twitter as shown below. Now I want to know how that is done. I wish to put flickering effect on any still image. I'd like to use that technique on not just still images, also image sequences. 
Thanks in advance.

Twitter link: https://twitter.com/mertakbal3/status/1197494768399527936

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

For this effect, you have to first install the **[Animation Nodes + Extra Nodes](https://github.com/3DSinghVFX/animation_nodes/releases)** because we need **UV Map Data Output** node ([learn more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHnpax7egHM)).

**Idea:** Distortion of image/movie coordinates in the material.

**Step-1:** Add image/movie as plane using *Images as Planes* option of the Blender. Then, setup the material like this in the image *(please note that the Generated and UV coordinates are added together)*,
[image]

**Step-2:** Then subdivide the image (or movie) plane few times,
[image]

**Step-3:** I have created a **2D Noise** group-node from two Vector Noise nodes which will use in the next step to set the UV coordinates for the plane,
[image]

**Step-4:** Now, compute the **2D Noise** based on the vertices of the plane then use that noise as UV coordinates in the **UV Map Data Output** node and adjust the parameters of **2D Noise** group-node based upon your requirement,
[image]

**Step-5:** Then you can also animate the z-value of Offset of **2D Noise** group-node,
 [image]

Final Node-Tree:
[image]

Blend File:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great lesson on Animation Nodes. I will soon create a new book for works of Animation Nodes in Blender 2.8 and I will soon move your nodes there. Page 5 and I hope you are ok with it. It is for study purpose only. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1rAuo1xAVLQNaETvWib8D829pBRbGyr2GNUfurnugsas/edit#slide=id.gcfc0de60262f53_3

Comment: Okay, no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

A similar range of effects can be created with shader nodes alone - (plenty of knobs to fiddle with to adjust it):

[image]

The 'Mix RGB' node is being (ab)used as a convenience, to mix XYZ vectors.

The 'Location' fields in the Mapping node are keyed.

Not quite the same depth as your reference, but I'm sure it can be tweaked.. or if you don't mind being uneconomical, you could even play with real refraction.

[image]

.. and the .gif is a bit crunched.

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant and thank you for the blend file.

Comment: Page 6 and I hope you are ok with it. It is for study purpose only. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1rAuo1xAVLQNaETvWib8D829pBRbGyr2GNUfurnugsas/edit#slide=id.gcfc0de60262f53_3

Comment: @Rita Yay! I'm famous! :D