# How to make a sine wave distortion effect?

Tags: shaders, 2d, distort

I'd like to achieve a simple wave distertion effect like the reflection has in this image:

[image]

I'd like to animate the reflection so I tried to do it with material nodes. I thought I should mix the UV mapping with a wave texture, but I must be missing something because I can not get enough control over the direction and the amplitude of the distortion. My current state:

[image]

How can this be done correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Mix color instead of Add color

Starting from a similar situation:

[image]
You should set up a wave texture with horizontal bands and a little bit of distortion:

[image]

Then Mix the coordinate of the UV map with the Wave texture. Keep the value low.

[image]

Finish by animating the values of the Wave texture in order to achieve the desidered result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was able to follow your steps and it looks way better now.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @Carlo, thank you for this answer. I am learning the usage of some nodes. Yours will help, as I too had last week asked for distortion effects on gif animation. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158950/how-to-distort-still-image-or-gif-animation