# How to achieve anime-like smears in blender?

Tags: effects

So I'm trying to do an anime-styled animation. I want to do something like a smear over the character when they move really quickly. Something like this:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve something like this in blender?

Edit: I've just tried something that kinda gets the effect I'm looking for. I took a plane and gave it a glass bsdf and then a noise texture, connected that up to a mapping node, and then altered the scale to give it this stretched look. I then put the glass in front of the model. Having the plane would help me animate this effect. The problem is that it affects the background as well. I'm wondering if there is a way to isolate this effect to just the model. [image]

Comment: you could try using motion blur.

Comment: I'm trying to get an anime aesthetic. Also, motion blur does not work in Eevee.

Comment: See the answers to my thread: How to distort gif animation? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158950/how-to-distort-still-image-or-gif-animation

Comment: It's not an image I want to distort. It's more like putting a lens up in front of an object and when you look through it the object becomes distorted... and then it only distorts that object and nothing else which loses the real-world comparison.

Comment: An easy way would be to separate the render into 2 passes. 1 with the glass and the smeared model, 1 with only the background, then combine them when compositing.

Comment: @covector How would you do that in 2.8?

Comment: Using view layers, you can first make a foreground layer which has your model and a plane behind your model with holdout shader node, then make a background layer with everything hidden, then you can composite all of it in the node editor, but since glass shader will not show transparent background, I would do the smearing in the node editor (at least idk how to make background appear transparent in glass shader, if there is a way to do so, you would include the glass in the foreground layer too and no need to do the smearing in node editor)

Comment: @covector I'm sorry. Thank you for all your help. I've never done work with other layers and compositing different layers together. I think I would need to see the process you've just mentioned so that I could follow along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after experimenting a bit with what covector said, I believe I have arrived at a solution. By using a combination of layers and scenes, I can now have an isolated "smear" effect on one object without affecting the other objects in the scene. [image]

I will continue to experiment with this to find a workflow for animation.

[image][image]
Note: Use the displace node to keyframe the effect.

I used two scenes: The first scene for the models and the second scene for the world texture. I then used the node setup provided by covector for the effect. After that, I used different render layer nodes and a z-combine to combine the layers into one composite. Thanks to everyone who helped out with this question.

[image]

Comment: Has anyone found a real time version of this for 2.9 or no, because I'm struggling with this one too. Trying to avoid the compositor as much as I can.

Answer (score 4):

**In node editor:**
You could try using the displace node which moves each pixel according to an input rgb, where red is how much the pixels will move in the x direction, and green is how much pixels will move in the y direction.

[image: Node set up for smearing]

(I didn't change any settings for the cloud texture, I just use the default values)

Edit:

**In 3d editor:**
If you want to do it directly on a 3d model in the 3d view, you can use the displace modifier.

1. create a cloud texture and make the size very small.
2. Then add the first sub-surf modifier if your model don't have enough geometry.
3. Then add the displace modifier under, and change the direction to only 1 direction (X, Y or Z)
4. Then add 1 more sub-surf modifier to smooth things out.

[image: do it in 3d editor]

Comment: Is it possible to get this effect over just a character model?

Comment: @JayPig i edited the answer and added how to get this effect only over a 3d model.