# Animation Nodes - Waveform Monitor - Picture into Grayscale into X-Distortion

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

I want to transform a picture with a given amount of pixels into a luminance signal (grayscale). The pixels are supposed to keep their Y-Position from the original input, but change the x-position based on their value between white an black. (So basically a waveform monitor). The final output should be in one color (green/black), but with the mentioned distortion.

Therefore I want to use the animation note add-on, but at the moment I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to distort still image or gif animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158950/how-to-distort-still-image-or-gif-animation)